# How to enable extensions that are not from Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

The new version of Chrome will auto disable extensions that are not from Chrome Web Store, and cannot enable it manually in the `chrome://extensions` page.

How to enable the extensions and disable the "auto-disable" mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the warning behavior.

You can, however upload extensions as private to the web store and install them from there, without suffering from any warnings/popups.

You can also enable developer mode and load unpacked extensions, but then it'll pop a warning every single time you start Chrome.

Comment: The second bit, works only on the dev channel

Comment: You are incorrect. I am on the stable channel and it works just fine.